# How to partition a string at a fixed index?

Tags: rust

I have a String (in particular a SHA1 hex digest) that I would like to split into two substrings - the first two characters and the rest of of the string.  Is there a clean way to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know that your string only contains ASCII characters (as in case with sha digests), you can use slices directly:

```
let s = "13e3f28a65a42bf6258cbd1d883d1ce3dac8f085";
let first = &s[..2];  // "13"
let rest = &s[2..];   // "e3f28a65a42bf6258cbd1d883d1ce3dac8f085"
```

It won't work correctly if your string contains non-ASCII characters because slicing uses byte offsets, and if any index used in slicing points into the middle of a code point representation, your program will panic.

Comment: On top of what Vladimir says, I would encourage you to create a *new type* for your SHA1, one that indicates that all the characters are alphanumeric (more restrictive than ASCII). You may then opt to store it internally in any fashion that makes sense (perhaps a Vec<u8>).

Comment: What can I do that will work for unicode characters?

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge you can use libraries like [unicode-segmentation](https://lib.rs/crates/unicode-segmentation). There is also the [chars()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) method on `str`, which may fit your purpose as well (it would depend on what kind of "unicode charaters" you mean here).

Answer (score 15):

There's a [split_at](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_at) method since Rust 1.4, use it like this:

```
let s = "13e3f28a65a42bf6258cbd1d883d1ce3dac8f085";
let (first, last) = s.split_at(2);

assert_eq!("13", first);
assert_eq!("e3f28a65a42bf6258cbd1d883d1ce3dac8f085", last);
```

Note that the index is a byte position and must lie on a character boundary. In this case this works because you know that your input string is ASCII.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you are expecting two `String`s instead of slices, you can use the `chars()` method and some `Iterator` methods to obtain them.

```
let text = "abcdefg".to_string();
let start: String = text.chars().take(2).collect();
let end: String = text.chars().skip(2).collect();
```

If you don't want to do heap allocations, you can use slices instead:

```
let start: &str = text.slice_chars(0, 2);
let end: &str = text.slice_chars(2, text.char_len());
```

Note that the slices version requires you to use unstable rust (nightly builds, not the beta)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to efficiently split a **String** into two **String**s, in case you have this owned string data case. The allocation of the input string is retained in the first piece by just using truncation.

```
/// Split a **String** at a particular index
///
/// **Panic** if **byte_index** is not a character boundary
fn split_string(mut s: String, byte_index: usize) -> (String, String)
{
    let tail = s[byte_index..].into();
    s.truncate(byte_index);
    (s, tail)
}
```

**Note:** The *.into()* method is from the generic conversion trait **Into** and in this case it converts **&str** into **String**.